# FrisbyJS returning 415 instead of 200

Tags: frisby.js

I just started using FrisbyJS to test a rest service we are building out.  I'm getting an error and that it says it's expecting a 415 instead of 200.  My code looks like:

```
var frisby = require("frisby");
var apiUrl = // api url
frisby.create("GET resource by id " + "43")
    .get(apiUrl + "/book/43")
    .expectStatus(200)
    .toss();
```

The exact error message is:

> Expected 415 to equal 200.

When I put the exact url that jasmine spits out to me when I run my test into a browser, or try it as a GET request in Postman on Chrome, it works and I get a 200 back.  For some reason I get a 415 though for my call.  Is there something I am missing?

### Edit

Tried to debug some more and if I just do

```
frisby.create("GET resource by id " + "43")
    .get(apiUrl + "/book/43")
    .inspectJSON()
    .toss();
```

I get this error:

```
Error parsing JSON string: Unexpected end of input
```

Which makes me thing that our rest service is doing something funny.  However when I view this url in a browser or Postman like I said, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your solution:

```js
frisby.globalSetup({
  request: {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
});
```